# ERROR: function unnest(integer[]) does not exist in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, rails-postgresql, postgresql-9.0, postgresql-8.4

```
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3,4])
```

While executing the above query I got the error like this:

```
ERROR: function unnest(integer[]) does not exist in postgresql.
```

I am using PostgreSQL 8.3 and I have installed the `_int.sql` package in my db for integer array operation.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`unnest()` is not part of the module `intarray`, but of standard PostgreSQL. However, you [need Postgres **8.4** or later](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/release-8-4.html#AEN97667) for that.

So you can resolve this by upgrading to a more recent version. See the [versioning policy of the PostgreSQL project](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Here's a poor man's `unnest()` for Postgres 8.4:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest(anyarray)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT $1[i] FROM generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) i';
```

Only works for **one-dimensional arrays** - as opposed to modern `unnest()` which also takes accepts multiple dimensions:

```
SELECT unnest('{1,2,3,4}'::int[])  -- works
SELECT unnest('{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}'::int[])  -- fails (returns all NULLs)
```

You *could* implement more functions for n-dimensional arrays:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest2(anyarray) -- for 2-dimensional arrays
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT $1[i][j]
FROM  (
   SELECT i, generate_series(array_lower($1,2), array_upper($1,2)) AS j
   FROM   generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) i
   ) sub;
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT unnest2('{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}'::int[])  -- works
```

You could also write a PL/pgSQL function that deals with multiple dimensions ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

(CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest(anyarray)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$BODY$
SELECT $1[i] FROM
    generate_series(array_lower($1,1),
                    array_upper($1,1)) i;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE)
by creating function like this I implemented the unnest function in postgresql 8.3

Comment: @AbdulRafiu: Yeah, that should do. I included you comment into my answer and added a bit.